# Being an adverb, can 'before' accompany 'past time adjuncts'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> 1. I think we've met before.
> 2. I think we've already met.
> 3. We’ve already discussed it yesterday.
> 4. *We’ve before discussed it yesterday.

An definition from Oxford Dic:

> at an earlier time; in the past; already

In the definition,'already' and 'before' seem to have the same interpretion. Why does #4 seem unnatural? Is there any cases where 'before' can accompany 'past time adjuncts'?

Comment: They don't have the same meaning.

Comment: We can say "I know we discussed it *before last week*. I remember a conversation we had months ago in which the subject came up."  But that's not the same as having **before** as a separate adjunct in its own right along with another time adjunct.

Comment: We've before discussed it. is not grammatical in English. The word before has to go after the verb +  object.

Answer (score 2):

**before** means "before now" or "at some time in the past" and thus it is vague and noncommittal with respect to when.  For that reason, it clashes semantically with **yesterday**, which is specific as to when.  It's like saying:

> We discussed it before now yesterday. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

And this too doesn't work:

> We discussed it yesterday before. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

The word **already** is connected to the present in a way that **yesterday** is not.  Where **yesterday** confines the verb to the past, **already** links the verb to the present, or to the "Now" of the utterance:

> The water is already boiling! Your electric kettle works well.
>
> They had already reached the city. The new train was super fast.

If your sentence did not contain both words, but **yesterday** only, the simple past would be the clear choice, not the present perfect:

> We discussed it yesterday.
>
> We have discussed it yesterday. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>
>
> We have discussed it earlier today. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

**earlier today**, though it is within spitting distance of the present, is nonetheless a past time reference.

Throwing **already** into the mix muddies the utterance so that the time-clash is not so strident, though this is still marginal to my ear:

> We have already discussed it yesterday. <sup>marginal</sup>

And a contracted form softens the clash even more:

> We've already discussed it yesterday. <sup>slightly less marginal</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You talk about adverbs accompanying adjuncts, so let's just clear something up - they can be the same thing.

An 'adjunct of time' is a broader term that refers to any word, phrase, or clause in a sentence that provides temporal information. So it can be an adverb, but not necessarily. Adjuncts can be more complex than simple adverbs of time, often adding additional information or context to the time frame in which an action or event occurs.

So let's not get too hung up about what we're calling them - fact is, you've got two in one sentence. Including two words or phrases that say the same thing in one sentence could be considered a *redundancy*, and some examples would be plain wrong; however, it could sometimes happen in everyday, extemporaneous speech.

> We already discussed this yesterday.

This is an example of something that might well be said by a native speaker, even though it isn't strictly correct. It is unnecessary to say both "already" *and* "yesterday", but when we speak extemporaneously we are thinking on the fly. Our first thought might be that we 'already' did this, but then we add the precise timing of 'yesterday' as a secondary, qualifying statement.

However, it would sound wrong if you said:

> Yesterday we discussed this already.

It sounds wrong because, having stated specifically that this took place *yesterday*, there is no need to used the less-detailed adverb 'already'. Unlike the previous example which is more than forgiveable, it would be a strange thought process that made you be specific in the first instance and then think to add a less-specific redundancy.